# How do I select specific data from a PowerShell object sourced from JSON data?

Tags: json, powershell

I have imported some JSON data and converted it to a PowerShell Object. I would like to understand how to retrieve specific portions of said data.

test.json:

```
{
  "Table": {
    "Users": {
      "Columns":   [ "[Id]", 
                       "[FName]",
                       "[MName]", 
                       "[SName]", 
                       "[UName]",
                       "[Pasword]" ],
      "data": "CustomUserData"
      },




    "Roles": { 
      "Columns": [ "[Id]",
                   "[Role]",
                   "[Description]" ],
        "data": "CustomRoleData"
                            }
              }
 }
```

Import to PS Object:

```
$userdata = Get-Content .\test.json |ConvertFrom-Json
```

Retrieve and format column data:

```
PS> $userdata = Get-Content ./test.json |ConvertFrom-Json
PS> $columns = $userdata.Table.Users.Columns -join ","
PS> $columns
[Id],[FName],[MName],[SName],[UName],[Pasword]
```

Example retrieval of custom data:

```
PS> $userdata.Table.Users.data
CustomUserData
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Select just the table names. When I try and do this by calling `$userdata.table` I get the following:

```
PS> $userdata.Table |Format-List


Users : @{Columns=System.Object[]; data=CustomUserData}
Roles : @{Columns=System.Object[]; data=CustomRoleData}
```

What I am looking for is just a list of the table names, in this case - `Users,Roles`

2. I would also like to know how to leverage this to create a ForEach loop which cycles through each table name and prints the columns associated with each table - ultimately I will be using this to craft a SQL query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.
It is a small function to output the property names recursively.

```
function Get-Properties($obj, [int]$level = 0) {
    $spacer = " "*$level
    $obj.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { 
        $spacer + $_.Name
        if ($_.Value -is [PSCustomObject]){
            Get-Properties $_.Value ($level + 2)
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
$userdata = Get-Content ./test.json | ConvertFrom-Json
Get-Properties $userData
```

The console output will look like this:

> ```
> Table
>   Users
>     Columns
>     data
>   Roles
>     Columns
>     data
> ```

Comment: This looks promising - I can certainly work with this. Thank you!!